# message sent from contact page dont reflect on the django admin database

Tags: django, model, django-admin

am working on contact me page where if a message/feedback is sent, it reflects in django admin database, the page seems to be working fine, however, when the message is sent, it does not show up in admin database

below is my models.py, views.py admin.py as well as part of my html file,

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Contacts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20 , null=True, editable=False, help_text="Name of sender")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50 , null=True, editable=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True, editable=False)
    message = models.TextField(null=True, editable=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Feedback"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + "" + self.email
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Contacts
#from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
#from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.  
def Contacts(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Feedback Submitted.')
       return redirect('Feedback')

    return render(request, 'Contacts/index.html', {})
def Feedback(request):
   return HttpResponse("Thank you for the feedback, a response will be sent to you shortly!")
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contacts

# Register your models here.
class ContactsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'subject','date',)
    search_fields = ('name', 'email',)
    date_hierarchy = 'date'

admin.site.register(Contacts, ContactsAdmin)
```

html file

```
         <form method="post" action="{% url 'Contacts' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="fname">First Name *</label>
          <input class="required form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name&nbsp;*" type="text" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="lname">Last Name *</label>
          <input class="required form-control" id="message-lname" name="message-lname" placeholder="Last Name&nbsp;*" type="text" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="contactEmail">Email *</label>
          <input type="email" class="required form-control h5-email" id="from-email" name="from-email" placeholder="Email&nbsp;*" type="text" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="contactPhone">Subject *</label>
          <input class="required form-control h5-phone" id="message-subject" name="message-subject" placeholder="Subject&nbsp;*" type="text" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="comment">Type your message here</label>
          <textarea class="required form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Type your message here&nbsp;*" rows="6" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-accent" type="submit">Submit</button>  
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the html form?

Comment: Are you using the admin console? If you're creating your own form and html page what is the reasoning for using ModelAdmin and the admin table in the database?